# ReactiveUI Viewinjection. How to do it right

Tags: c#, mvvm, memory-leaks, dispose, reactiveui

I will try to explain my problem as detailed as possible. My application is composed using mvvm and has a shellview which loads some static views. heres comes question 1:
Is it a good practice to instantiate these viewmodels in the shellviewmodel ?

```
public ShellViewModel(IScreen screen)
    {
        HostScreen = screen;


        LogoViewModel = new LogoViewModel(HostScreen);
        ...
        StatusViewModel = new StatusViewModel();

    }
```

Anyways I also have a static view which has a list, whose ItemSource property is bound to a ReactiveList

```
     public ShiftOrderView()//ShiftOrderViewModel viewModel)
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                this.WhenActivated(
                    d =>
                        {
                            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ProductionOrderList, v => v.ShiftOrder.ItemsSource).AddTo(d);
    });
}
```

Now Whenever the user selects a new list item this item is displayed in another view. I am currently doing this via navigation

```
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            this.WhenAnyObservable(o => o.ProductionOrderList.ItemChanged)
                .Where(x => x.PropertyName == "ItemsLeft")
                .Select(x => x.Sender)
                .Where(x => x.ItemsLeft == 0)
                .Subscribe(x =>
                {

                    ProductionOrderList.Remove(x);
                }).AddTo(d);

            this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.SelectedProductionOrderViewModel).Where(pvm => pvm != null)
                .Subscribe(pvm =>
                {
                    HostScreen.Router.NavigateAndReset.Execute(
                        new ProductionOrderDetailViewModel(HostScreen,
                        Locator.CurrentMutable.GetService<IProductionItemService>(), pvm));
                }).AddTo(d);

        });
```

but I think this is not the right way and introduces a memory leak. As you can see in the code above Items get removed from the list when their itemsleft property reaches 0. But I am not sure how to properly Dispose of these Items. If I create a new instance in the navigate method, will the old new ProductionOrderDetailViewModel get disposed? If not how can I achieve this?
I am sure I missed some parts needed for a correct answer, so please ask and I will provide the information you need.

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: I have a feeling you are using the wrong words here. ``Items get removed from the list when their itemsleft property reaches 0``. Do you mean ``Senders get removed from the list when their itemsleft property reaches 0``

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the pattern of problem you have and I recognise it. You have a property of type `T : IDisposable` and when that property is updated you wish to dispose the old version. I have an extension method for `IObservable<T>` that will solve this kind of problem in a general way.

The extension method is

```
    public static IDisposable SubscribeDisposable<T>
        (this IObservable<T> observable, Func<T, IDisposable> action)
    {
        var d = new SerialDisposable();
        return observable
            .Finally(() => d.Dispose())
            .Subscribe(e =>
            {
                d.Disposable = Disposable.Empty;
                d.Disposable = action(e);
            });
    }
```

and you can use it like

```
this
  .WhenAnyValue(p=>p.DisposableProperty)
  .SubscribeDisposable(v=>v)
  .AddTo(d);
```

but normally I place more complex stuff in the `SubscribeDisposable`. For example in some of my code I have

```
 this.LoadUnloadHandler(() => this
                .WhenAnyValue(p => p.ViewModel)
                .WhereNotNull()
                .SubscribeDisposable(x=>x.StartAnimation()));
```

Whenever my viewmodel changes I need to stop the old animation and start a new one. The easiest way is that `StartAnimation()` returns an `IDisposable` that stops the animation. `SubscribeDisposable` ensures that the old `IDisposable` is disposed before the new one is created and thus the animations are neatly sequenced.

Just for clarity the `StartAnimation` method.

```
public IDisposable StartAnimation() {  
    return Animation = new PlayController(
        maximum: 2 * Math.PI,
        minSpeed: Math.PI / 180 * 10,
        maxSpeed: 2 * Math.PI,
        currentSpeed: Math.PI,
        jogAmount: Math.PI / 50,
        fps: 120,
        modes: new Dictionary<AnimationMode, string>
        {
            { AnimationMode.PlayOnce, "Play once" },
            { AnimationMode.PlayAndReverse, "Play and reverse" },
            { AnimationMode.Loop, "Loop" }
        }) { StickyWidth = 50 };
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.